# Implementing three nested for loops in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to make 3 for loops using assembly language all I can do is 2 for loops one in the internal and one external.
here is what i tried

```
name "loops"
org 100h
mov bx, 0  ; total step counter
mov cx, 5
k1: add bx, 1         
mov al, '1'
mov ah, 0eh
int 10h 
push cx
mov cx, 5
  k2: add bx, 1  
  mov al, '2'
  mov ah, 0eh
  int 10h      
  push cx
     mov cx, 5
     k3: add bx, 1 
     mov al, '3'
     mov ah, 0eh
     int 10h
     loop k3    ; internal in internal loop.
  pop  cx
  loop  k2      ; internal loop.
pop cx
loop k1             ; external loop.


; wait any key...
mov ah, 1
int 21h

ret
```

I created this simple code out of an example.

Comment: No one is forcing you to use `loop`, you can just use regular `cmp/test`+conditional jmp

Comment: The code looks correct and should work.

However:

Are you aware that for function 0Eh, interrupt 10h BX has some meaning?

Maybe int 10h will modify CX (depending on the BIOS/DOS version used)...

You say the program doesn't work. What does it really do?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your program under MS-DOS 6.22 in a VMWare virtual machine and it ran absolutely perfectly!

So it is probable that your BIOS, DOS or DOS Emulator has a problem with "int 10h". "int 10h" is nothing that a special variant of "call" so it depends on the BIOS or operating system what "int 10h" really does.

Maybe the version you are using is modifying the CX register.

MS-DOS 6.22 and the BIOS used by VMWare however will execute your program without problems!